# unmount USB drive in C++

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu

I am developing a Qt application for Linux (Ubuntu) in which I use USB drive to backup some content. Application should unmount the target drive after copying stuff. I have a `udev` rule file to mount USB at a specific location with `ENV{mount_options}="relatime,users,umask=0,uid=user,gid=user"` where user represents my user name.

I tried using this without any luck.

```
const char* usb = "/mnt/mountpoint/usbdrive";
if (!umount(usb))
{
  qDebug() << "Device unmounted";
}
else
{
  qDebug() << "Can't unmount" << strerror(errno); //this prints Operation not permitted
}
```

Could someone please help me here? Am I using `umount` right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Appropriate privilege (Linux: the [CAP_SYS_ADMIN](http://www.lindevdoc.org/wiki/CAP_SYS_ADMIN) capability) is
>   required to unmount file systems.

Per [`umount`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/umount) the code is fine. However you need privilege to umount devices.

The [CAP_SYS_ADMIN](http://www.lindevdoc.org/wiki/CAP_SYS_ADMIN) capability allows a process to perform various administrative tasks, namely: calling mount(), umount(). There are two worth articles about *capabilities* here:

- [CAP_SYS_ADMIN: the new root](https://lwn.net/Articles/486306/)
- [Overview of Linux capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) (List of capabilities)

Comment: Just for interest, if you grant your app `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` or setuid you have to be very careful wrt the use of mount (and probably umount) as mount itself can definitely be used for local privilege escalation. See [this exploit](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/18071/) which overlays /etc/passwd with a copy containing a known root password. +1 for capabilities rather than SUID :)

Comment: @m-m. do I need to run my application as root? if yes, this may not be possible.

Comment: @AntonyVennard: Nice, I just added an article which argued about security issues too.

Comment: @ramtheconqueror: Read [_CAP_SYS_ADMIN: the new root_](https://lwn.net/Articles/486306/) it explained about it, I think you don't need be _root_ to have that privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Add to `/etc/sudoers` line:

```
user ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/umount
```

where `user` is your user's name.

Instead of using `umount ...` use `sudo -u user umount ...`

Comment: Sorry, this won't work. As I mentioned in the question, we need to do this programmatically i.e., terminal won't be available for the user. Thanks.