# What is the use of cap_set_proc() if the program needs to be run as root

Tags: c++, system, mount, capability, umount

I am trying to unmount a usb-storage device through a c++ program, using `umount2()` function. Since [umount2() needs administrative privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671417/unmount-usb-drive-in-c), I implemented umount2() with cap_set_proc() as follows

```
  cap_t caps;
  cap_value_t cap_list[1];
  caps = cap_get_proc();
  if (caps == NULL)
      std::cout << "cap_get_proc failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  cap_list[0] = CAP_SYS_ADMIN;
  if (cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_EFFECTIVE, 1, cap_list, CAP_SET) == -1)
      std::cout << "cap_set_flags failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  if (cap_set_proc(caps) == -1)
      std::cout << "cap_set_proc failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  else
  {
    while(umount2("/media/user/usb_storage_device", MNT_DETACH))
    {
      std::cout << "ERROR: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(2));
    }
    std::cout << "Unmounted!" << std::endl;
  }
  if (cap_free(caps) == -1)
      std::cout << "cap_free failed: " << strerror(errno) std::endl;
```

But when I run the above code as a normal user I get error:

> "cap_set_proc failed: Operation not permitted"

But, if I run the code as a root, usb-storage device is unmounted successfully. So my question is, what is the use of using cap_set_proc() to provide administrative privileges, if the cap_set_proc() function itself needs root privileges to execute? 
Am I doing something wrong here?

Also,is it possible to actually use cap_set_proc() without executing the program with sudo?

Please help.

Comment: You can be an user with CAP_SETPCAP.

Comment: @KamilCuk Do you mean I should add CAP_SETPCAP to cap_list in my code and then use cap_set_proc()?

Comment: No. I mean that you can call `cap_get_proc()` if you are an user with CAP_SETPCAP capabilities granted. The root user has CAP_SYS_ADMIN so it can probably just call `cap_get_proc()` `umount2` as it is. The user you are trying to call `cap_set_proc` probably doesn't has `CAP_SETPCAP` capabilities granted, thus you get operation not permitted.

Comment: @KamilCuk From what I understand, you are saying that I am not a user with CAP_SETCAP capabilities. So my question is how do I grant these capabilities?

Comment: I suggest you read through the [capabilities manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html). You can either inherit capabilities (i.e. a process sets up the capabilities for you before executing your program), or have these associated via the file system.